# STM32L0 Snippets with GCC ARM Toolchain

Tags: stm32, arm, linux, gcc, stm32cubemx

Currently I try to use the STM32L0 microcontroller series. I found that ST offers a low-level C program collection called [STM32SnippetsL0](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1898/PF260788) too, parallel with their complex STM32CubeMX based HAL API. Unfortunately I can not use the codes under GNU/Linux because it supports only EWARM and MDK-ARM toolchains. Are there any possibilities to run this code with the [GCC ARM Embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) toolchain?

Comment: sounds like a stackoverflow question.  why cant you use ewarm?  what libraries are not working?  can you link in the other libraries?  ewarm is a gnu compiler toolchain as well yes?  so you should be able to link them in.

Comment: Thank you for your hints @dwelch. AFAIK EWARM is based on the C compiler of IAR Systems. It runs only under Windows and I want to find a GNU/Linux based solution.

Comment: ahh sorry I was thinking of a different compiler, a gnu based cross compiler for windows, nevermind...you might still be able to link, and/or if they have the source code to the library you can re-compile.  I cant imagine that st delivers the board/chip support package without sources somewere and/or without a gnu based set of libraries.  If they dont offer that then I wouldnt bother with it and find another solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long experiment I can say it is possible to compile the STM32Snippets with the GCC ARM Embedded toolchain. The Snippets contains itself the necessary files except the linker file. I used a linker file copied from STM32CubeMX (SW4STM32 template) but I think other scripts are also usable.

It is necessary to copy two files from the Snippets template folder (Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Source/Templates). The first is system_stm32l0xx.c and the second the appropriate startup assembly file from gcc sub-folder. (Yes it seems to partial support for gcc.) I used startup_stm32l053xx.s because I use Nucleo board. If the downloaded Snippets is extracted to the folder snippets and arm-none-eabi-gcc is in your path you can use the following code:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DSTM32L053xx -Wall -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -march=armv6-m -mlittle-endian -Isnippets/Drivers/CMSIS/Include -Isnippets/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Include -Wl,--gc-sections,-Map=main.map -Tstm32l053xx.ld -L. system_stm32l0xx.c startup_stm32l053xx.s main.c -o main.elf
```

Finally bin is produced to upload to Nucleo.

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin
```